# Capture API request-response by 3rd Party libraries like Stripe

Tags: java, api, logging, stripe-payments, interceptor

This might not even exist but I want to know if anyone is able to capture API requests by services like Stripe etc.

For example, if I use `Charge.create(params)` from here [`create a Charge`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create), is there any way I can log the request-response of the API request? Maybe it is possible to add an [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) in a hacky way?

If you don't use this, what are the best practices for logging operations achieved through API?

I went down the rabbit hole in Stripe lib for Java ([stripe-java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java)) and could see that it gets executed by a class that is at least 7-8 modules deep.

Comment: Have you looked at documented API @ https://stripe.com/docs/api ? It's a public API so the 7-8 deep module can only be calling this.

Answer (score 0):

As emeraldjava said, stripe-java (and all other Stripe bindings) use the public facing Stripe API under the hood.

Wanting to capture API requests is a little weird as you're the one making those calls in the first place, so you already know what's in the request.

In the case of `Charge.create(params)` the parts you're interested in are already in `params`. That function will return the response from the Stripe API.

If for some reason you really want to know everything about the request (like headers for example), you can make the same API call with `curl`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=curl